# ORACLE - materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, materialized-views

I am trying to create materialazed view.

I have 2 databazses ORA1 and ORA2. I have table POKUS on ORA1 and I am trying to create view on ORA2 which change every time when I change and commint changes on ORA1 in table POKUS.

This is my query. but it is not working:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  
REPLIKOVANY_POKUS2 
REFRESH FAST START WITH 
    SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 1/24/60 
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM dovondrda3.POKUS@ora1.uhk.cz;
```

Can you help me pleas

Comment: You should learn very quickly that when you ask for help on a site like this, "it is not working" will not elicit many good answers. How is it "not working"? What is happening - are you getting a syntax error? A runtime error? No error, but it just doesn't do what you want it to do? "It is not working" is not a technical description of the problem. Then: refreshing every hour as in your code is not the same as "every time I change and commit changes on ORA1". Which do you need - "every time you make changes and commit", as you say in words, or "every hour" as you coded it?

Answer (score 0):

> which change every time when I change and commint changes on ORA1

Well, you can't do that, not over database link as refreshing `on commit` won't work when remote database is involved. It is documented somewhere in Data Warehousing guide; search for it, if you want.

Remote database:

```
SQL> create table a1_brisime as
  2  select * from tom
  3  where sifra = '0387779';

Table created.

SQL> alter table a1_brisime add constraint pkab primary key (sifra);

Table altered.

SQL> create materialized view log on a1_brisime;

Materialized view log created.

SQL>
```

Local database:

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_test
  2  refresh fast on commit as
  3  select sifra, naziv
  4  from a1_brisime@dbl_test
create materialized view mv_test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view


SQL>
```

As I said - it won't work. Therefore, switch to another option, e.g. `on demand`:

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_test
  2  refresh on demand as
  3  select sifra, naziv
  4  from a1_brisime@dbl_test

Materialized view created.

SQL>
```

Or scheduled (as you tried):

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_test
  2  refresh complete
  3  start with sysdate
  4  next sysdate + 1/24/60
  5  as
  6  select sifra, naziv
  7  from a1_brisime@dbl_test

Materialized view created.

SQL>
```